# Nodemon execute function before every restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals, nodemon

I have a `Node.js` game server and I start it by running `nodemon app.js`. Now, every time I edit a file the server restarts. I have implemented `save` and `load` functions and I want every time the game server restarts (due to the file chages) the game to be saved before restarting so that I can `load` the previous state after the restart.

Something like this is what I want:

```
process.on('restart', function(doneCallback) {
   saveGame(doneCallback);
   // The save game is async because it is writing toa file
}
```

I have tried using the `SIGUR2` event but it was never triggered. This is what I tried, but the function was never called.

```
// Save game before restarting
process.once('SIGUSR2', function () {
     console.log('SIGUR2');
     game.saveGame(function() {
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
     });
});
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/events.md `nodemon.on('restart',...)` ?

Comment: @migg No, didn't have the `nodemon` package included, will take a look.

Comment: @migg Nope, that event is not called.

Comment: So again, I start nodemon from the console command.

Comment: So did you find anything useful for this? @Cristy

Comment: @AnandUndavia I don't really remember, I think I didn't manage to make it work on Windows, and what I did was just having saves/snapshopts at a regular interval, if the server failed/restarted I would just load the latest available snapshopt.

Answer (score 3):

Below code works properly in Unix machine. Now, As your saveGame is asynchronous you have to call process.kill from within the callback.

```
process.once('SIGUSR2', function() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('Shutting Down!');
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
    },3000);

});
```

So, your code looks fine as long as you execute your callback function from within the `game.saveGame()` function.

```
// Save game before restarting
process.once('SIGUSR2', function () {
     console.log('SIGUR2');
     game.saveGame(function() {
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
     });
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question, all you said is that my code is working fine, but in my case it isn't (on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

on Windows

run app like this:

```
nodemon --signal SIGINT app.js
```

in app.js add code

```
let process = require('process');

process.once('SIGINT', function () {
  console.log('SIGINT received');
  your_func();
});
```